# How to have multiple rows for fluidRow titlePanel R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Is there some way to render 2 rows for titlePanel in R Shiny?  For example, the below renders only the first fluidRow

```
titlePanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(6,div(style = "height:200px;background-color: yellow;", "Topleft")),
      column(6,div(style = "height:100px;background-color: blue;", "Topright"))),
    fluidRow(
      column(6,div(style = "height:100px;background-color: green;", "Bottomleft")),
      column(6,div(style = "height:150px;background-color: red;", "Bottomright")))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it with header panel:

```
headerPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(6,div(style = "height:200px;background-color: yellow;", "Topleft")),
      column(6,div(style = "height:100px;background-color: blue;", "Topright"))),
    fluidRow(
      column(6,div(style = "height:100px;background-color: green;", "Bottomleft")),
      column(6,div(style = "height:150px;background-color: red;", "Bottomright")))
)
```